# Vue2 js получить вывести количество элементов

Tags: vue.js

Как вывести общее количество элементов с помощью переменной {{ count }}?
Код:

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="task in tasks" :class="{ 'is-completed' : task.completed }">{{ task.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Tasks',
        data() {
            return {
                tasks: [{
                    name: 'Go to work',
                    completed: true
                }, {
                    name: 'Go to store',
                    completed: true
                }, {
                    name: 'Go to home',
                    completed: false
                }]
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .is-completed {
        text-decoration: line-through;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Элементов чего? И где у вас объявленя переменная `count`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tasks: [
      {
        name: 'Go to work',
        completed: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Go to store',
        completed: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Go to home',
        completed: false
      }
    ],
    count: 0,
  },
  mounted() {
    this.count = this.tasks.length;
  },
  methods: {
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <span>Кол-во елементов: </span>{{ count }}
  </template>
</div>
```